# Android webview - Enable Private Browsing

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to create a webview in adroid with **private browsing** enabled.

public WebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, boolean privateBrowsing)

Since: API Level 11
Constructs a new WebView with layout parameters and a default style.

**context** - a Context object used to access application assets. **attrs** - an AttributeSet passed to our parent. **defStyle** - the default style resource ID. **privateBrowsing** -     whether this WebView will be initialized in private mode.

Can anyone please explain me how to implement it with a breif example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    WebView webView = new WebView(this, null, R.id.webView1, true); 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView.loadUrl("google.com");
    Log.v("PrivateBrowsing", "" + webView.isPrivateBrowsingEnabled()); << returns true for me
```

R.id.webview should be in your layout xml. Hope this works...

Comment: Cool. Thats creates a webview and opens url. But  **webview.isPrivateBrowsingEnabled()** returns **false**

WebView webView = new WebView(this, null, R.id.webView1, true);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
Log.v("PrivateBrowsing", "" + webView.isPrivateBrowsingEnabled());

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you using a Device with Android 3 or 4?

Comment: I am testing on the emulator with Android 4.0

Comment: WebView webView = new WebView(this, null, R.id.webView1, true); 
webView.isPrivateBrowsingEnabled() // returns true 
webView.loadUrl("google.com");
webView.isPrivateBrowsingEnabled() // returns false